# SharedPreferences doesn't store values after closing app

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I tried to store some values in ArrayList by SharedPreferences by the following code:

```
public static String jsonSavePracticeResult;
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesSaveResults = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

public void savePracticeResults(ArrayList<KeepPracticeResultsModel> 
arrayListPracticeResult) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    jsonSavePracticeResult = gson.toJson(arrayListPracticeResult);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editorSharedPreferencesSaveResults;
    editorSharedPreferencesSaveResults = 
    sharedPreferencesSaveResults.edit();
    editorSharedPreferencesSaveResults.clear();
    editorSharedPreferencesSaveResults
    .putString("donePracticeList",jsonSavePracticeResult);
        editorSharedPreferencesSaveResults.apply();
}
```

After that, I retrieved values by the following code:

```
public ArrayList<KeepPracticeResultsModel> getSavedPracticeResults(){

        jsonSavePracticeResult = sharedPreferencesSaveResults.getString("donePracticeList", jsonSavePracticeResult);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<KeepPracticeResultsModel>>() {}.getType();
        keepPracticeResultsModels = gson.fromJson(jsonSavePracticeResult, type);
        return keepPracticeResultsModels;
}
```

When app is open, it works fine, but when you try to close app from recent apps, and after that you open app again, SharedPreferences values are lost and jsonSavePracticeResult is Null!
Also I called `getSavedPracticeResults()` in `onResume()` and `onPause()`.

I did all of the solutions that existed in StackOverflow but it's happening again!

Comment: post some more code specially related to `sharedPreferencesSaveResults`

Comment: @Omer I added `sharedPreferencesSaveResults` in the code.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier No, because of I debugged app when is running, that method stored all of values and you can retrieve those by return `keepPracticeResultsModels`, but after closing it from recent apps, if you enter app again `jsonSavePracticeResult` is null

Comment: Did you check this ? https://www.journaldev.com/9412/android-shared-preferences-example-tutorial I use it before and works like charm! :)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using `.commit()` instead?

Change

```
 editorSharedPreferencesSaveResults.apply();
```

to

```
 editorSharedPreferencesSaveResults.commit();
```

The reason being that `.apply()` writes in the background, asynchronously; wherever as `.commit()` will write right away. So, if you're closing your app, you want to quickly save these changes before the app is closed.

Comment: Yes, I tested it actually before sent this post, it didn't work